# Determining whether the expression is nonnegative or not

Tags: algebra-precalculus

After a number of steps, I managed to simplify my own problem. The last step is that showing whether the following expression is greater/less than equal to 0 or not. All the variables involved ($k_1$ and $k_2$) are real and $a,b$ are positive real constants. Here is the equation:
$$b^2{k_1}^2+4a*b*{k_1}{k_2}+a^2{k_2}^2,\ a,b>0$$
I know this rather simple, however, after hours of work, I'm simply stuck here. I am open to any help.

Comment: Let $$a=1,b=1,k_1=1,k_2=-1$$

Comment: You mean an *expression* rather than an equation.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is equal to
$$
(ak_2+bk_1)^2+2abk_1k_2,
$$
so if you choose $a,b,k_1,k_2$ cleverly, you see that the expression can be negative as well.

$a=b=k_1=1$ and $k_2=-1$ should do the trick, in case you can't come up with anything yourself. I hope this helped!

Comment: I forgot to add something. $k_1$ and $k_2$ are any real numbers, and $a,b$ are positive real constants.

Comment: @user722271 Unclear what the relevance is of your last comment.  jasnee's answer has $a = b = 1$ which satisfies that $a,b$ are positive.

Comment: @user722271 Umm, okay? That changes nothing though.

Comment: I see that right now. Sorry to bother you. Depending on my choice, the equation may be positive or negative. Thanks!

Comment: @user722271 No worries, glad I could help!